# Reload QQuickView into the same window container

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2

I want to write plugins to my program as qml displaying inside dock widget

I load plugin this way:

```
if (!qview) 
  qview = new QQuickView();
qview->engine()->clearComponentCache();
qview->setSource(QUrl(path));
QQuickItem *item_main = qview->rootObject();
QWindow* main_page = item_main->window();  
auto container = QWidget::createWindowContainer( main_page, ui- >dockWidgetContents );
container->show();
```

It works ok, but reloading plugin is quite slow and causes flickering. I think it is because createWindowContainer creates native window each time.
**Can I speed up reloading by forcing QQuickView use the same window container after reload or somehow avoid window flickering?**

Answer (score 0):

The solution happens to be quite simple:

```
if (!qview) {
  QWindow *wnd = new QWindow();
  QWidget::createWindowContainer(wnd, ui->dockWidgetContents )->show();
  qview = new QQuickView(wnd);
}
```